# Paste and reference to undefined active cell

Tags: vba

I am copying a value from one workbook to another and, when I paste it, I need the value to link back to its original source. I got it to work that the cell hyperlinks. However, I'm pasting into a variable cell, so it keeps pasting in the wrong location. Does anyone know how to make where I put stars ** below refer to the active cell?

```
Dim rng, clm As Range
With ActiveWindow
    Set rng = Cells(ActiveCell.Row)
    Set clm = Cells(ActiveCell.Column)
    rng.Activate
    clm.Activate
    End With

With ActiveCell
Selection.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

With ActiveCell
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(**rng, clm**), Address:=FilePath, ScreenTip:="The screenTIP", TextToDisplay:=FilePath
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of the second `With ActiveCell`:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:=FilePath, ScreenTip:="The screenTIP", TextToDisplay:=FilePath
End With
```